# Configuring and troubleshooting IPv6 routing on multi-interface Cisco router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ipv6

I recently purchased a new Cisco router for my IPv6 network. I configured the correct IPv6 addresses on all the interfaces and enabled the interfaces on the network. I'm able to ping all of the interfaces that I configured on the local subnet. But other Users are complaining that they cannot access information from other subnets or the Internet on our network. What Ipv6 command can I use to resolve this issue?

Comment: if you can communicate on the subnet, but not outside of it then you need to look at your routes. The cisco does not know how to (or cannot) direct clients outward. Can it ping its gateway?

Comment: yes, I'm able to ping my gateway. I can ping all interfaces but cannot access any information on my subnets or the internet?

Answer (score 1):

Run "show config" and give the output to someone who knows Cisco IOS and IPv6 routing.
:-)

It's not a matter of running a command or two. It's a matter of thinking through what you were trying to do, and what you actually did, and how it went wrong. It may involve capturing packets and analyzing them to see what's not working.

To get better help, update your question with the details of what addresses, prefixes, routes, and router advertisements you set up. A simple diagram of the parts of the network involved would help too.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some commands to set up basic routing on a Cisco router:

```
ipv6 unicast-routing
ipv6 cef
no ipv6 source-route
```

Setting up a default route:

```
ipv6 route ::/0 <ipv6-address-of-gw>
```

If you run NTP you need to secure that to prevent being used for DDOS amplification attacks. You can use the Team Cymru [Secure NTP Template](http://www.team-cymru.org/ReadingRoom/Templates/secure-ntp-template.html) for IPv4. The IPv6 versions of the commands that I use are:

```
ntp access-group ipv6 peer NTP-servers-v6
ntp access-group ipv6 serve DENY-v6
ntp access-group ipv6 serve-only NTP-clients-v6
ntp access-group ipv6 query-only DENY-v6
```